# error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof ChartTypeRegistry'

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

**home.component.ts**

```js
global: boolean = false;
country!: string;
data: GlobalData;
dailyData: any[] = [];
countries: any[] = [];
lineChartData: any[] = [
  {
    data: [65, 64, 33, 44],
    label: 'Temp label'
  }
];
lineChartType = "line";
lineChartLabels: any[] = [
  'label01', 'label02', 'label03'
];
barChartData: any[] = [
  {
      data: [65, 76, 33],
      label: 'Label'
  }
];
```

**home.component.html**

```
<canvas baseChart
    [chartType] = "lineChartType"
    [datasets] = "lineChartData"
    [labels] = "lineChartLabels"
>
</canvas>
```

Error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof ChartTypeRegistry'

Error-line:

```
[chartType] = "lineChartType"
```

The error occurred in home.component.html

I need a solution. Try to find out the solution on google but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

FYI, **`ChartTypeRegistry` was introduced by chart.js in [version 3.0 and later](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.0.2/api/interfaces/charttyperegistry.html).**

Hence, I conclude that you installed chart.js that is incompatible with the latest ng2-chart (version 2.4.2).

To reproduce the same issue, I have installed **chart.js version 3.4** as the link below:

[Sample project (**chart.js v 3.4**)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3xy6se)

---

### Solution (chart.js version before 3.0)

According to [ng2-charts - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts),

You need to install chart.js with:

```
npm install chart.js@2.9.4
```

OR

```
npm install @types/chart.js@2.9.33
```

[Sample solution (**chart.js v 2.9.4**)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6qst1v)

---

### Solution (chart.js version 3.0 and later)

Specify `lineChartType` with `ChartType` type.

```js
import { ChartType } from 'chart.js';

public lineChartType: ChartType = "line";
```

[Sample solution (**chart.js v 3.0**)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vnu9vz)

Comment: I tried, but it's not working. Same error

Comment: Can you show your angular.json in the question? Or you may create a Minimal, Reproducible Example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com).

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WelOrG3FdsASgXTn-_i70uMgIeNLYCdW/view?usp=sharing
here is the angular.json file's link

Comment: Oops, sorry for wrong mention,  can you show package.json? Thanks.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F2zI7dtoRx1lYokmz6zsJ_NUF8OFeNk2/view?usp=sharing
here is the link of package.json file

Comment: Okay thanks, checked that the versions for ng2-chart and chart.js installed are correct. Not sure it works, you may try to re-install these 2 libraries and restart your Angular App. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234510/discussion-between-mahfuz-shuvo-and-yong-shun).

Answer (score 0):

There is example Chart.js from 4.0.1 + version, like I resolved

```
    import { Chart, ChartType } from 'chart.js/auto';

    chartTypes: {[key: string]: ChartType} = {
       line: 'line',
       bar: 'bar'
    };

    //...code
    lineChartType = this.lineChartType['line'];
```